# Advice on Large Number of Routes

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-routing

In our RouteConfig in an effort to have company profiles names as the some of our root URLs, we are adding a route for each company name, eg. xyz.com/acme

Whilst this appears to be working ok, I was hoping for some general advice on this, or a better way to solve it. I'm particularly concerned about performance, especially as we grow and we may have 10000+ companies and therefore 10000+ routes.

The code looks something like this:

```
foreach (string companyName in companyNameList)
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: companyName,
        url: companyName,
        defaults: new { controller = "CompanyProfile", action = "Index" });
}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you not have a single route of the following form:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{company}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "CompanyProfile", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { company= new CompanyConstraint(companyNames) });
```

Where `CompanyConstraint` is an `IRouteConstraint` that checks to ensure that the that the company name is valid? Something like this:

```
internal class CompanyConstraint: IRouteConstraint
{
    public CompanyConstaint(IList<string> companies)
    {
        this.companies = companies;
    }

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        object company;
        if (!values.TryGetValue("company", out company) || company == null)
        {
             return false;
        }

        return companies.Contains(company.ToString());
    }
}
```

Cheers,
Dean

Comment: Probably best to make sure the `IList<string>` is a `HashSet<string>` so that `.Contains` runs as fast as possible!